# UIDynamics for heatmap

Tags: ios, dictionary, uikit-dynamics, uidynamicbehavior

For a customer I need to realize a `UIView` which should resemble this one:

[To be screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsPiJ.png)

My idea was to use `UIDynamics` and some sort of `UIFieldBehaviour`. So I created a container view `containerView`, added a bunch of `UIView`s. Those internal views are added to a `UIFieldBehavior.magneticField()` (using addItem).

I also create a `UICollisionBehaviour` adding the same `UIView`s

Here below the code:

```
let  _animator = UIDynamicAnimator.init(referenceView: self.pointsReceivedMap)
let _magnet = UIFieldBehavior.magneticField()
let _collisions = UICollisionBehaviour()
_collisions.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = true

for index in 1..<10 {
    let view = UIView();
    /*add some UI style to view */
    _collision.addItem(view)
    _magnet.addItem(view)
}

_animator.addBehaviour(_magnet)
_animator.addBehaviour(_collision)
```

And this is what I get:

[What I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkiCj.png)

The yellow view is the container view passed as `referenceView` when the animator object is inited (`self.pointsReceivedMap`)

Comment: Why did you choose to use a magnetic field?

Comment: Actually I tought it could be the only way to describe the magnetic behaviour I wanted, but I'm a beginner! Do you have any suggestion about? Maybe the gravity field is better? Thanks!!